# Regex for python: how do I extract a string between words?

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have a sentence:

```
Meet me at 201 South First St. at noon
```

And I want to get the address like this:

```
South First
```

What would be the appropriate Regex expression for it ? I currently have this, but it is not working:

```
 x = re.search(r"\d+\s?=([A-Z][a-z]*)\s(Rd.|Dr.|Ave.|St.)",searchstring)
```

Where searchstring is the sentence. The address is always preceded by 1 or more digits followed by a space and followed by either Rd. Dr. Ave. or St. The address also always starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

The first group, the part where you try to match the address is `[A-Z][a-z]*`, it means one uppercase letter followed by any lowercase letters. Probably what you want is any uppercase or lowercase letter or space: `[A-Za-z ]*`. Also note that the dots in the second group mean any character and not the literal `.`, so you have to escape it. The solution would look like this:

```py
>>> re.search(r'\d+\s?([A-Za-z ]*)\s+(Rd|Dr|Ave|St)\.', 'Meet me at 201 South First St. at noon')[1]
'South First'
```

Or just use `.` to accept anything.

```py
>>> re.search(r'\d+\s?(.*?)\s+(Rd|Dr|Ave|St)\.', 'Meet me at 201 South First St. at noon')[1]
'South First'
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I add the space in what I have?

Comment: @lameprogrammer01 I updated my answer to include answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
\d+\s*([A-Z].*?)\s+(?:Rd|Dr|Ave|St)\.
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9IjUIX/2).

**Details**

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `([A-Z].*?)` - capturing group #1: an uppercase ASCII letter and then any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:Rd|Dr|Ave|St)` - `Rd`, `Dr`, `Ave` or `St`
- `\.` - a dot

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tciLbX):

```
m = re.search(r'\d+\s*([A-Z].*?)\s+(?:Rd|Dr|Ave|St)\.', text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output: `South First`.

Comment: Thank you. Why do we use group(1) ?

Comment: @lameprogrammer01 Because the value you need is captured in Group 1. The text matched before or after it is just context, it is still there in `m.group()`.

Comment: That makes sense. How do we make sure the first letter of the address is a capital?

Comment: @lameprogrammer01 If you do not care for Unicode use `r'\d+\s*([A-Z].*?)\s+(?:Rd|Dr|Ave|St)\.'`. I updated the solution to make sure it starts with `[A-Z]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
import re
s = 'Meet me at 201 South First St. at noon'
print(re.findall('(?<=\d )[A-Z].*(?= d.|Dr.|Ave.|St.)', s)[0])
```

Output:

```
'South First'
```